# Chartjs-node installation failing

Tags: node.js, chart.js

I am getting an error while installing dependencies for chartjs-node module

```
make: Entering directory `/home/jazz-2016/apps/scrapperapp/node_modules/canvas/build'
  SOLINK_MODULE(target) Release/obj.target/canvas-postbuild.node
  COPY Release/canvas-postbuild.node
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/Canvas.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasGradient.o
  CXX(target) Release/obj.target/canvas/src/CanvasPattern.o
In file included from ../src/CanvasPattern.cc:9:0:
../src/Image.h:19:21: fatal error: gif_lib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gif_lib.h>
                     ^
compilation terminated.
```

It has dependencies over canvas,jsdom and chartjs,but while installing those individually gives me the same error.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little old query, still might be useful to someone else. 
I solved it by running:

```
sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev libjpeg8-dev libpango1.0-dev libgif-dev
```

These dependencies are needed before you do:

```
npm install chartjs-node
```

I hope this will fix and if still unable to proceed, comment below and I may help you out further as I was in the same situation.